# Html class leaking

Tags: php, html, class

Hi super simple question here,

I am making an upload page for my website and am attempting to implement a download bar. No php is hooked into it yet but I am trying to make the layout.  All is good however I can not seem to find out why my class wont apply to the upload bar..the first class is "leaking" into it if you will. I tried to google it first but everything is very broad obviously.  Progress bar starts at ther bottom of the html. Sorry for the wall I didnt know where I steered wrong.

progress bar dream...
[image]

progress bar reality...
[image]
closer look: http://samplepackgenerator.com/phUploader.php

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title><?php echo $samplepackgenerator; ?>Upload Sounds</title>
</head>
<?
If($password_form) {

    Echo $password_form;

} Else {
?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="phuploader">
<body align="center" class="mbr-box mbr-section mbr-section--relative mbr-section--fixed-size mbr-section--full-height mbr-section--bg-adapted " id="header2-0" style="background-image: url(assets/images/studio2.png);">
    <tr>
        <td class="table_header" colspan="2"><b><?=$samplepackuploader;?></b> </td>
    </tr>

    <?If($display_message){?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="message">
        <br />
            <?=$display_message;?>
        <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?}?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="upload_info">
            <b>Allowed Types:</b> <?=implode($allow_types, ", ");?><br />
            <b>Max file size:</b> <?=$max_file_size?>kb.<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?For($i=0;$i <= 0;$i++) {?>
        <tr>
        <!--    <td class="table_body" width="80%"><input type="file" name="file[]" size="30" /></td> -->
        </tr>
    <?}?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="table_footer">
        <div> 



<!--     Upload       -->       
        <a href="#" class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg animated fadeInUp delay btn-default" type="button" name="file[]" onclick="document.getElementById('fileID').click(); return true;">Upload</a> <input id="fileID" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; " />





<!--     Confirm       -->          
            <input class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg animated fadeInUp delay btn-default" type="submit" value=" Confirm " name="submit" /> 

<!--     Back       -->         
        <a         class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg animated fadeInUp delay btn-default" href="index.html"  >Back<a 

        </a>


        </div>


        </td>
    </tr>



</body>
</form>
<?}//Please leave this here.. it really dosen't make people hate you or make your site look bad.. ?>




<tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="progress">
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="50" style="width: 100%;">
    <span>HELLO</span>
  </div>
</div>
    </td>
    </tr>




</html>
```

THE CSS

```
body{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 40%;
}
.progress span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by leaking into it?

Comment: What haakon said, it looks like a progress bar? Do you want it in your block?

Comment: the first class is applying to the bar even after I indicated a new class @haakon319

Comment: i wanted it to look the the "progress" class but one of the other classes is overriding it @Darren

Comment: You can easily find out which class - if so - by right clicking in your browser and "inspecting" the css. Use Chrome or Firefox or Safari, all have "inspectors" nowadays. You can see all classes and ids and those which are overridden are shown as stroke through.

Comment: @AlexanderTrust wow thank you that is super helpful, i did not know that

Comment: And to make sure your `span` code would be accessed write `.progress-bar span` instead. Letting out layers of containers results easily in errors. And another thing strikes me, you do have `tr` and `td` tags but you do not have `table` tags. Why is that? This way your code never would be interpreted as W3C compliant.